# Is there any way to modify and update time format in a variable without writing a new .nc file?

Tags: python, time-series, netcdf

I have a gridded monthly rainfall dataset. I want to modify and update the date format in 'Day' variable within your existing NetCDF file without creating an entirely new file. In the original file it's in YYYYMMDD format. I converted it to YYYY-MM-DD format but how can I display the new date format when I call the .nc file?

Here the code I used -

```
dsPcAD = xr.open_dataset("E:\\rainfall\\BDGR_High_Res_Monthly_Rainfall_1901-2018.nc")

time_data = dsPcAD.variables['Day'][:]

formatted_dates = [datetime.strptime(str(int(date)), '%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for date in time_data]
```

[This is how the original data looks like -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF91U.png) -

[This is the modified date which I want when I call the .nc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JyjW.png)

I tried to convert the date format from YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD and I want 'Day' variable to show the new time format when I call the variable.

Comment: Not sure what the question is here.  Don't see any attempt to write the formatted dates to the NetCDF file.  Converting time_data (binary numbers) to a datetime string would require creating a new NetCDF variable (an array of chars).  Writing to the existing file will require opening the dataset in append/write mode, e.g. mode='a'

Comment: Thank you Eric. But it's showing me permission denied everytime I'm trying to write the formatted dates to the NetCDF file.

Comment: Do you have permission to write to that file?

Comment: @TimRoberts no. It shows permission denied

Comment: If you don't have permission to write that file, then there's nothing you can do in your code.  You need to deal with your IT team to get write permission.